# Dynamically enable/disable FXBlurView

Tags: ios, performance, xamarin, xamarin.ios, blur

I have an app where I blur the navigationbar and tabbar. Here I use FXBlurView to easily do this. I have noticed that the blur keeps being refreshed even though the view doesn't change. This causes the battery to drain quicker than I would want.

Is there a way to quickly detect if the view has changed, without having to take a snapshot (which also is +-5ms each time)?

Comment: @accfews I ended up using the default navigationbar and tabbar, they have an optimized blur without having to add additional code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods for scroll changes and easily set `dynamic` property to `true/false`

As another option you can change `updateInterval` to a bigger value to provide delayed refreshes.